# UIImagePicker in Landscape mode IOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

My app uses the landscape mode and need to access the photo gallery. Appears this error: Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [PUUIAlbumListViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'

```
    var image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self

    image.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false

    self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIImagePickerController):

> The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only.